# invert letters in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to invert "z" and "y" letters in one column.
Test column looks like
A
1234z12
123y12
12z134
12z123y2

At the momment I'm using forumla 
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*y*";A1));SUBSTITUTE(A1;"y";"z"); SUBSTITUTE(A1;"z";"y"))
which works great for values that have only one letter "z" or "y", but when it comes to value like
12z123y2 it converts only "y" letter.
Any sugestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the y to something temporary, for example:

```
*y*
```

then change the z to y, then change the  temporary y value to z. This way you are not overwriting by changing y to z, then z back to y. So you dont need an IF anymore:

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"y","*y*"),"z","y" ), "*y*", "z")
```

Comment: thnx, works great. I totally forgot to use temporary variable